# Checking for multiple route paths in vue v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently adding a class to a li element based on the route.path using the following code;

```html
<li v-bind:class="{ 'current': $route.path == '/services' }"><nuxt-link to="/services">Services</nuxt-link>
```

I want to check for multiple paths but i am unsure if that is possible.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to check for mulitple paths by using an array of possible values, and then [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check for existence:

```html
<li v-bind:class="{ 'current': ['/services', '/contact', '/about'].includes($route.path) }">
```

To improve template readability, consider moving that to a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties):

```html
<template>
  <li v-bind:class="myClasses">
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    myClasses() {
      return {
        const possiblePaths = ['/services', '/contact', '/about']
        current: possiblePaths.includes(this.$route.path)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```